# If I created a BufferedReader instance with a paramater which is from FileReader, which one do I have to close?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, filewriter, printwriter

I created the following readers, writers etc. in a Java class:

```
// reader
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filetoread);

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(reader);

// writer
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filetowrite);

PrintWriter writerpw = new PrintWriter(writer);

StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(r);
```

I have some questions about closing them:

1, How should I close in the the case of reading?

```
reader.close();
r.close();
```

Should I close both, or closing one will close the other?

2, How should I close in the case of writer?

```
writer.close();
writerpw.close();
```

Should I close both, or closing one will close the other?

Comment: Close the outermost one.

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficient to close the outermost one as it will also close the one it wraps (the `close` method of the `BufferedReader` calls `in.close()` internally, where `in` is the reader it wraps).

At the same time, when creating the reader within the `try-with-resources` statement you won't need to close any of them explicitly as this will be done for you automatically:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```